# Why can I use this "private" value constructor?

Tags: haskell

I put this in Shapes.hs:

```
module Shapes   
( Shape(Rectangle)
) where 

data Shape = Circle | Rectangle deriving (Show)
```

Then I go into GHCi and load it with `:l Shapes`.

Typing `Circle` works. I only specified `Rectangle` in the paranthesis, so why does it work?

Comment: That's because you're not importing the module `Shapes`. You're directly loading the file `Shapes.hs`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a side effect of using `:load`.  If you instead used

```
ghci> :m +Shapes
```

or

```
ghci> import Shapes
```

you wouldn't be able to access the `Circle` constructor.

Comment: This does not work. If I do `:m +Shapes` or `import Shapes` I get `<no location info>: Could not find module 'Shapes' It is not a module in the current program, or in any known package.` I did run GHCi from the same directory as where Shapes.hs is located

Comment: did you compile it using `ghc -c Shapes.hs`?

Comment: Yes, I just tried and it didn't help. I still get the same error during `import Shapes` or `:m +Shapes`. (By the way, this section doesn't mention that I have to compile with `ghc -c` first: http://learnyouahaskell.com/modules#making-our-own-modules) Any other ideas?

Answer (score 4):

After your `:l module` or `:l module.hs`, you are in the full top-level scope of module `module`, that is why `Circle` is in scope in your case.

See: [The effect of :load on what is in scope](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/interactive-evaluation.html#ghci-scope)

Answer (score 3):

Because ":l" in ghci reads the file and interprets it. It's not the same as "import".