# Why can't I import this Haskell module?

Tags: haskell

I put this in `~/Desktop/Shapes.hs`:

```
module Shapes   
( Shape(Rectangle)
) where 

data Shape = Circle | Rectangle deriving (Show)
```

I then do this:

```
cd ~/Desktop
ghci

ghci> :m +Shapes

<no location info>:
    Could not find module `Shapes'
    It is not a module in the current program, or in any known package.

ghci> import Shapes

<no location info>:
    Could not find module `Shapes'
    It is not a module in the current program, or in any known package.
```

Why do I get this error?

I also tried compiling first with `ghc -c Shapes.hs`. It still doesn't work.

I installed the "Haskell Platform 2013.2.0.0 for Mac OS X, 64 bit" from haskell.org on my OS X 10.9.2 Mavericks. I also followed their `ghc-clang-wrapper` instructions.

**Update:**

Someone suggested doing `:l Shapes.hs` first. The problem is that `:l Shapes.hs` loads the **entire Shapes file**, meaning I have access to the `Circle` value constructor even if I did not export it. See my earlier question: [Why can I use this "private" value constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23409916) I want to load **only the module**. Is this possible?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31732605/how-can-i-import-a-haskell-module-in-ghci) helped me to get it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to load your `Shapes.hs` first by `:l Shapes.hs`.

1. Because your `Shapes` have not been loaded, so `:m Shapes` will not work.
2. Because your `Shapes` does not exist in a compiled package that `ghci` can find, so `import Shapes` will not work.

If you only want the exported symbols in scope, after `:load` a module, you could use `:module` or `import` to only import those symbols. For example, after `:load Shapes.hs` and `:module Shapes`, `Rectangle` will in scope but `Circle` will not.

See:
[What's really in scope at the prompt?](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/interactive-evaluation.html#ghci-scope)
[:module and :load](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/interactive-evaluation.html#idp6981600)

Comment: I have updated my question with a problem about this.

Comment: @stackoverflowuser First `:load Shapes.hs`, then `:module Shapes`.